# Nginx reverse proxy response webp / text/html instead of image

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have nginx config like this, image will have a path starting from /images/... and it will be pointing back to 192.168.xx.xx:3333

```
location /images/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.xx.xx:3333/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout 120s;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

instead of returning the image, it returns a buffer string, can someone help me?

I tried changing the config many times, but it didn't work.